# Comparison between the current date and previous date and update the target

Tags: sql, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Suppose the source data seems to be like below:

```
Subscrn_id    Product       start_date    Stop_date   Regi_id    Status
================================================================================
10            xyz           01-jan-2014    null               123        Active
20            xyz           01-jan-2013   01-jan-2014     456        Expired
30            xyz           01-jan-2012   01-aug-2013      678        Expired
40            abc           01-jan-2014    null                678        Active
50            xyz           01-jan-2012   01-jan-2014      910        Expired  
60            abc           01-jan-2014   05-jan-2014       910        expired
70            def           05-jan-2014       null              910        Active
```

Assume your processing date is 01-jan-2014

For these regis, the start_date, stop_date should be populated as below:

```
Regi        start_date   Stop_date
===================================
123          01-jan-2014   null
456          01-jan-2013   01-jan-2014
678          01-jan-2014   null
910          01-jan-2012   null
```

Meaning for the same regi_id if the stop_data and start date is same then the target start date should be updated as the previous  start date,

For ex in regi_id 678 since the stop date of subscrn id 30 and start date of subscrn id 40 is not equal we need to update the target start date as 01-jan-2014.

In regi_id 910 since the stop date of subscrn id 50 and start date of subscrn is 60 is same and stop date of subscrn id 60 is same as start date of subscrn id 70  we need to update the target start date as 01-jan-2012 as shown in below output:

Comment: Have you missed showing the expected output?

Comment: The output should be as shown above in the second table displayed

Answer (score 0):

If I managed to understand correctly, something like this should do the trick for you:

```
UPDATE subscrn s
   SET s.start_date =
          (SELECT stop_date
             FROM regi r
            WHERE r.regi_id = s.regi_id)
 WHERE s.start_date != (SELECT stop_date
                                      FROM regi r
                                     WHERE r.regi_id = s.regi_id)
```

This statement will update the start dates in your target table based on the regi_id (only if they are different. You can omit the where clause as you will still get the desired result (same dates based on the regi_id)...

Comment: This will not work as initially the REGI_USERS table will have the start date and stop date columns as null.We need to update these 2 columns based on the regi_id's from source.